# Convert a character to numeric without a format in SAS?

Tags: string, text, sas, numeric

I know this has to be a simple question but I'm having difficulty converting a character variable into a numeric variable.

I have a column in a dataset with about 1.7 million rows that measures the number of months for something to occur.

It is recorded as a character variable written down as: "X months" where X shows the number of months.

How can I convert "X Months" Char into X numeric?

Comment: What have you tried? In this case it's an INFORMAT and tells SAS how to read the data so not sure why you say you 'without a format' here.  And I'm also guessing it's not just X months, make sure to provide enough sample data to illustrate your problem. As posted this question does not meet SO guideline because you haven't shown any attempt at solving the issue so far - you may have done so, but you haven't shown it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
data have ;
  infile cards dsd ;
  input oldvar:$10.;
datalines4;
4 months
3 months
17 months
111 months
;;;;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  newvar=input(scan(oldvar,1),8.);
run;
```

As you can see below, the resulting `newvar` variable has no format:

[image]